# ubuntu bind9 AppArmor read permission denied (chroot jail)

Tags: ubuntu, bind, chroot

I am trying to run bind9 with chroot jail. I followed the steps mentioned at : http://www.howtoforge.com/debian_bind9_master_slave_system

I am getting the following errors in my syslog:

```
Jul 27 16:53:49 conf002 named[3988]: starting BIND 9.7.3 -u bind -t /var/lib/named
Jul 27 16:53:49 conf002 named[3988]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-dlz-postgres=no' '--with-dlz-mysql=no' '--with-dlz-bdb=yes' '--with-dlz-filesystem=yes' '--with-dlz-ldap=yes' '--with-dlz-stub=yes' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions' 'CPPFLAGS='
Jul 27 16:53:49 conf002 named[3988]: adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1048576
Jul 27 16:53:49 conf002 named[3988]: found 4 CPUs, using 4 worker threads
Jul 27 16:53:49 conf002 named[3988]: using up to 4096 sockets
Jul 27 16:53:49 conf002 named[3988]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Jul 27 16:53:49 conf002 named[3988]: none:0: open: /etc/bind/named.conf: permission denied
Jul 27 16:53:49 conf002 named[3988]: loading configuration: permission denied
Jul 27 16:53:49 conf002 named[3988]: exiting (due to fatal error)
Jul 27 16:53:49 conf002 kernel: [74323.514875] type=1400 audit(1343433229.352:108): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=3987 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/lib/named/etc/bind/named.conf" pid=3992 comm="named" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=103 ouid=103
```

Looks like the process can not read the file `/var/lib/named/etc/bind/named.conf`. I have made sure that the owner of this file is user bind, and it has the read/write access to it:

```
root@test:/var/lib/named/etc/bind# ls -atl
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 3 bind bind 4096 2012-07-27 16:35 ..
drwxrwsrwx 2 bind bind 4096 2012-07-27 15:26 zones
drwxr-sr-x 3 bind bind 4096 2012-07-26 21:36 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind  666 2012-07-26 21:33 named.conf.options
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind  514 2012-07-26 21:18 named.conf.local
-rw-r----- 1 bind bind   77 2012-07-25 00:25 rndc.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind 2544 2011-07-14 06:31 bind.keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind  237 2011-07-14 06:31 db.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind  271 2011-07-14 06:31 db.127
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind  237 2011-07-14 06:31 db.255
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind  353 2011-07-14 06:31 db.empty
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind  270 2011-07-14 06:31 db.local
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind 2994 2011-07-14 06:31 db.root
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind  463 2011-07-14 06:31 named.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind  490 2011-07-14 06:31 named.conf.default-zones
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind 1317 2011-07-14 06:31 zones.rfc1918
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

You need to edit `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` to give Bind permission to access those files in the chroot. You basically want to modify all the paths specified there to be prefixed by the chroot location. Run `service apparmor reload` after making the changes.

Answer (score 3):

```
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/named/run-root/etc/named.conf"
```

It says, it need permissions to access these folders.
You should add

```
/var/named/** r,
```

in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named
then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Apparmor and bind9 have some conflicts with Plesk.

Edit the file `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named` and add:

`/var/named/run-root/** rwm,`

Reload and restart:

`service apparmor reload 
service bind9 start`

Now everything should work properly.

Comment: Why do you think plesk is involved here?

Comment: I had the same problem days ago. After an automatic update of plesk I got the same error. Some research on google showed that people often have that problem with plesk, bind9 and apparmor.

Comment: Fair enough, but this would be a more convicing answer if you included some pointers to those posts.